# Set focus on input after it's showed by v-show

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a simple form that is hidden when the page is loaded, using v-show. I want to focus the input after showing it. I have a button to call a a method that shows the form and sets the focus to the input using this code:

```
    this.newQuestion = true; //(Form whit v-show:newQuestion)
    this.$refs.questionInput.focus();
```

The problem is that the form is showed correctly, but the input isn't focused the first time I press the button, if I press it for a second time when the form is in the page it works. I want to know if there is a way to do this, thanks.

Comment: Is `this.$refs.questionInput` referencing another component?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem before, and I forced the update (in your case, the `focus`) by using Vue's `nextTick` method, which is to use immediately after you’ve changed some data to wait for the DOM update.:

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.$refs.questionInput.focus();
})
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick, I only added $el to reference the input inside the nextTick method so it ended this.$el.$refs.questionInput.focus(); and worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad I could help, I'd very appreciate it if you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var me = this;
Vue.nextTick(function() {
  me.$refs.questionInput.focus();
});
```

Comment: Is it necessary to keep reference for `this` in `me` variable? Can we just use `this` in `$nextTick` callback ?

Comment: Ideally, but vue hoses 'this' in certain places, I'm not entirely clear on the reason

Comment: That's not a Vue thing, it's just JavaScript.  The value of `this` will change depending on [context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#function_context)